# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function even though function is defined in included file

Tags: php, function, scope

main.php requires 2 files:

```
require './functions/fileA.php';
require './functions/fileB.php';
```

fileA.pgp as a function

```
function doecho($url){echo $url}
```

In fileB.php, I have a function that calls the doecho function

```
function withinBfunction($url){doecho($url);}
```

But I get this error,

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl().
```

However, if, in fileB.php I call the doecho function outside any function, it works.
It seems that the functions in fileB.php cannot access the functions on fileA.php

I took a look at this post ([PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function when function is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817133/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-when-function-is-defined/49542590#49542590)) but the difference is that I am not using classes. Any ideas how I could solve this?

Oh, and, yes, I have turned on the php error log with  (error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED) and all I get is that "call to undefined function".

Comment: `include` does not die if the file can't be loaded. use `require` to make sure the file is loaded correctly.

Comment: Are you sure that `fileA.php` is included? Maybe the interpreter cannot find it and the warning it triggers is suppressed by your configuration. Use [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) instead.

Comment: If PHP says it's not there, it's not there, no matter what you think.

Comment: May be you are missing one period in `include './functions/fileB.php';`. Try `include '../functions/fileB.php';`

Comment: @Dormilich, I am using require now. Still, no good results.I also a preatymuxh ure that the files are being loaded because I tested some echos and they show up.

Comment: maybe you got a namespace defined somewhere?

Comment: display errors would have helped you, try debugging before you ask for help. https://stackoverflow.com/q/5438060/3664960

Comment: @dajeval, Thank you for your comment. However I have been looking at the php errors, yes. And all  I get is that Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl(). That is why I am asking for help here.

Comment: @Jeff, thank you for commenting. I am not recalling using namespaces.

Comment: @axiac, I changed to require. Same issue. Also nothing helpful shows in the error logs (error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED)) except the Call to undefined function ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use two dots for one directory up like:
Include '../directory name';

Comment: Hi. Don't think that is the problem. I a using now "require", instead of "include". Both included files are in he same folder. If I put two dots, require fails.